# ASP.NET Core Tag Helper Intellisense in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am unable to get Intellisense for all tags (e.g. `asp-for` `asp-action`, etc.) I'm running Visual Studio 2017.

My `.csproj` file includes the  following packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools" Version="1.1.0-preview4-final" Type=""/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor" Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime" Version="1.1.0" />
```

and my `_ViewImports.cshtml` file includes the following:

`@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers`

Is there something I need to edit or add?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For **VS2017 RTM** (if you've upgraded by now) you need to install *Razor Language Services* from *Extensions and Updates...* in *Tools* menu within Visual Studio.

**Caveat**: It seems as if you also have to remove any `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools` reference (I had version `1.1.0-preview4-final`) from your *.csproj* file to enable IntelliSense after installing the extension above.

Answer (score 8):

[Solved] In my updated `Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise 26430.13` i solved my problem with disable and re-enable `Razor Language Services` and it's working now.

I know that's little weird. I find `Razor Language Services` in `Extension and Update` from `Tools` menu and `Disable` it and restart Visual Studio and Enable it again and restart Visual Studio again and finally everything's right.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your findings. As weird it may sound it worked for me. I've `VS2017  ver 15.0.26430.14` . Even after installing `Razor Language Services` it was not working (no intellisense, no coloring of tag helpers attributes). Followed your steps to make it work.

Comment: Didn't work for me just disabling it. I then did the long route by just uninstalling it(then the vs installer also uninstalls the whole of asp.net because they are dependent). Then I reinstalled the asp.net feature from the installer(get tools and features) and it worked(you get Razor Language Features along with it).

Comment: Worked. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT1:**

As suggested in VS2017 known issues, workaround is now available. For this, we need to install the [Razor Language Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-madsk.RazorLanguageServices) extension. This extension provides support for ASP.NET Core Razor Tag Helpers in Visual Studio 2017.

---

**Original:**

Razor Tag Helpers do not get colorization or special IntelliSense at design time in **VS2017 RC**.  They work normally at runtime. No workaround available at this moment.

Refer [known-issues-vs2017](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/blob/master/known-issues-vs2017.md#tag-helpers-do-not-work) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can add/use the tag helpers by doing the following process:

1. **Create View** with the name of **_ViewImports.cshtml**
2. Add the following line into it,
        **@addTagHelper "*,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers"**
3. **Done**[image]

Go check **_Layout.cshtml**, it will be working fine.

Comment: If you have recently add areas. you need to move _ViewImport from views to root folder