# Complete check for build asp.net mvc core 2.0 application without publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

When I publish a ASP.NET Core MVC 2.0 Project, the Visual Studio does a complete check fore every view (.cshtml file) for variable name consistency. This is perfect for catching small errors that slip by.

How can I do this check without publishing the application, for instance during compile/build time?

Comment: do you mean during compile/build time ?

Comment: yes, I edited the question.

Comment: Have you tried to do a rebuild?

Comment: normal builds/rebuild does not check the views. only publishing

Comment: You could try extensions like resharper (maybe not the one you need but the name was readily available).  I have pretty good intelisense in the views in my work projects and have to assume it is from extensions the other devs have installed.

Comment: Also, see these 2 pages:  http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/e58d2fbe-23b5-4bab-95ec-54ee749cce6c.aspx                             and:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42279865/asp-net-core-tag-helper-intellisense-in-visual-studio-2017

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you need is to enable Razor views precompilation during the Build. By default Razor views are compiled only during Publish.

Add `PrecompileRazorViews` target to your csproj file:

```
<Target Name="PrecompileRazorViews"
        AfterTargets="Build"
        DependsOnTargets="MvcRazorPrecompile" />
```